# How do I set a MySQL field to be the dynamically generated value of another field?

Tags: mysql, drupal

I'm mucking around with drupal, and it has two fields called `nid` and `vid` on its node table. Every record I look at seems to have the same value for both `nid` and `vid`.

I'm hacking around and inserting nodes the non-drupal way, and I want to make sure `vid` is set to whatever value `nid` has.

For sake of explanation, here's something that I'd hope for:

```
INSERT INTO node (vid, type, blah, blah) VALUES (value_of(nid), "webpage", "blah", "blah");
```

`value_of` doesn't exist of course, but hopefully you get the idea of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create an insert trigger.

Comment: Are you writing the `INSERT` statement by hand? If so, just fill in the same value for `nid` as you did for `vid`. I can't imagine a simpler, easier to understand/maintain solution than that. But if you're not writing the `INSERT`s by hand, how are they generated? That will play heavily into the solution.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135033/drupal-what-does-vid-mean-in-drupal to know what they both are, you might not want to always have them the same.

Comment: I think I've worked around it. I'm letting vid default to 0, then calling `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` and doing an `UPDATE` to set the `vid`.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple: I am forming the statement by hand, but the `nid` field is automatically generated via the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property of MySQL. I don't know what the value will be until the statement executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some vital understanding.

- {node} holds info about each node, the pk and serial is the nid (node id), the vid is a reference to the {node_revisions} table.
- {node_revisions} holds info about the body field of a node. Here vid is the pk and serial while it also has a nid which is a reference to the {node} table.

One node can have multiple revisions. This makes it possible to save old versions of the same node. If you never make a new revision to a node, the nid and vid will be the same, but for each new revision that's made, the vid will increase while the nid stays the same.

So in short, nid and vid shouldn't be equal, but in some cases they are. You should you the {node_revisions} to get the vid for your insert to the {node} table.

Comment: Thanks. I'm writing a simple dev/production sync script, and with your information I just updated it to grab each node_revision as well as each node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nodefactory](http://drupal.org/project/node_factory) module to create new node. It doesn't brake drupal db structure and creates nodes with all necessary fields filled. Then you can use even cck fields. This is right way to create nodes from your code.